# VB.NET Host Conectivity Issue

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, hosting

I have a VB.NET solution that is connected with a database that is hosted online. Everything works fine at home, but when I try to use it with another internet connection, it does not connect

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? I'm aware that it might be firewall settings etc, but not too sure where to look, the internet does not seem to have much resources with regards to this issue also

Thanks a million for your help in advance

Updated:

Error message is "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL Hosts"

Comment: Too much left unsaid... "does not connect" is not even close to enough information. Voting to close until more info is provided.

Comment: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts"

There's your error message Joel